# mcrypt_decrypt is not working properly

Tags: php, encryption

I'm working on a simple Zend application and I need to encrypt all the financial figures before storing them in the database, and decrypt them when needed. I used `mcrypt_encrypt()` and `mcrypt_decrypt()`. As I need to decrypt the figures I used a constant initialization vector(iv), which is not at all recommended.

here is my code:

```
define ('string','WdryhedeescmsfkirYNemsjdesapQ');
define ('iv', '$356?dWuSkm)@g%dnw#8mA*');

class FormatValues {

 const string= 'WdryhedeescmsfkirYNemsjdesapQ';
 const iv = '$356?dWuSkm)@g%dnw#8mA*';

 public function encrypt($val){
    $enc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $val,self::string , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,self::iv);
    return $enc;
 }

 public function decrypt($val){
    $dec = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $val,self::string , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,self::iv), "\0");
    return $dec;

 }
}
```

The `encrypt()` method encrypts the data, but when decrypting, it doesn't give the correct figure.

Why is this? Is there some other way to encrypt and decrypt data without having a constant iv?

Thanks in advance

Charu

Comment: In what sort of field are you storing this data in the database? You should be using a `VARBINARY` or `BLOB` field for this, if you are not, make sure the byte string you retrieve from the database is the same as the one you inserted.

Comment: thanks!! I think the problem is there!!! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use something like that for my project, try it !

```
$key = 'password to (en/de)crypt';
$string = ' string to be encrypted '; // note the spaces

$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

echo 'Encrypted:' . "\n";
var_dump($encrypted);

echo "\n";

echo 'Decrypted:' . "\n";
var_dump($decrypted); // spaces are preserved
```

Comment: How to do the same in java?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the correct answer but, you should definitely not define a constant called `string` as it is a reserved keyword in PHP.

Comment: This is a good point, but definitely a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Geoffrey Brier thanks for your point... I will change the name of the constant