# encrypted and decrypted results are different when using mcrypt_ecb() function in php

Tags: php

I am using the following function to encrypt and decrypt

```
define('KEYVAL',"hgfzhjh");
function encryption($plain_text)
{
$key_value = KEYVAL;
$encrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key_value, $plain_text, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
return $encrypted_text;
}

function decryption($encrypted_text)
{
$key_value = KEYVAL;
$decrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key_value, $encrypted_text, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
return $decrypted_text;
}

echo $id = 'abc';
echo "<br />";    
$enc = encryption('abc');
echo $dec = decryption($enc);   
echo "<br />";
echo $dec;
echo "<br />";
echo strcmp($id,$dec);
```

Although the echo of **`$enc`** and **`$dec`** is same but
the result of **`strcmp`** is -5. Why..?

I am fetching data from database using the decrypted result but it is unable to fetch data because both strings are not same.
please let me know if I am not using it correctly..

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.5.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have doubts, just **`var_dump`** your string. `var_dump($dec)` gives the length of **`8`**, that is why your **`strcmp`** gave you **`-5`**

Decryption here gives you extra spaces on the end of the string, so make use of a **`rtrim`**

### You need to trim the decrypted string in the function itself !.

```
function decryption($encrypted_text)
{
$key_value = KEYVAL;
$decrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $key_value, $encrypted_text, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
return rtrim($decrypted_text); //Trimming here
}
```

Btw .. why spaces are getting added ? Have a look at this [`thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493335/php-mcrypt-why-to-add-spaces-on-string-input)

Answer (score 1):

trim your encrypted value

```
$enc = trim(encryption('abc'));
```